# Как реализовать вертикальную прокрутку внутри Div'a?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть картинка шириной в 400px и в высотой в 1500px, + есть див с размерами 400х500, нужно сделать так что бы картинка отображалась только внутри дива и что бы можно было ее скролить вертикально ( без ползунка скрола желательно ), как это реализовать?

Comment: вот https://cloud.mail.ru/public/EJUM/Uth3XaQLe  архив , посмотри , точнее наведи курсор на картинку , и отпишись

Answer (score 1):

**Решил таким способом:**

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  width: 420px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
img { width: 400px;}
```